# Transpose Matrix // C++

Tags: c++

Here is My code, it's finding the Transpose of a Matrix, but columns and rows are the same as the input 10*5.

If entered:

```
1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Deserved output is:

```
1  11 21 31 41
2  12 22 32 42
3  13 23 33 43
4  14 24 34 44
5  15 25 35 45
6  16 26 36 46
7  17 27 37 47
8  18 28 38 48
9  19 29 39 49
10 20 30 40 50
```

Here is My code, it's finding the Transpose of a Matrix, but columns and rows are the same as the input 10*5.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        int a[10][10], trans[10][10], i, j;
        int r = 10;
        int c = 5;
    
     
        for(i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        {
          
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    
    
        for(i = 0; i < r; ++i)
            for(j = 0; j < c; ++j)
            {
                trans[j][i]=a[i][j];
            }
    
    
        for(i = 0; i < c; ++i)
            for(j = 0; j < r; ++j)
            {
                cout << " " << trans[i][j];
                if(j == r - 1)
                    cout << endl;
            }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Note, that can't use any other functions, libraries, etc..:

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 rows and 10 columns of input, so

```
        int r = 10;
        int c = 5;
```

should be

```
        int r = 5;
        int c = 10;
```

Also to match the output to the desired output,

```
                cout << " " << trans[i][j];
                if(j == r - 1)
                    cout << endl;
```

should be

```
                cout << trans[i][j];
                if (trans[i][j] < 10) cout << " ";
                if(j == r - 1)
                    cout << endl;
                else
                    cout << " ";
```

because

- One more space should be printed after one-digit numbers
- No space should be printed before the first numbers in each rows

Comment: ohh, sorry for my dumb question lol)) solved it, thanks))